# collapsible list with dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nested-lists, dynamic-content

I have tried all kinds of lists I found all over the internet, but none of them seem to properly work. I think the reason for this might be the fact that the content of the list is dynamically loaded (with JQuery ajax).

On `$(document).ready` I load the list and append the html data to the `div`.

After that I try to make the list collapsible (the list is nested, it's a navigation for a database).

My best try so far:

```js
function loadNavigation() {
  var _url = "http://api.writeplace.nl/idofnavigation
 var credentials = btoa("username:password!");
  
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
     "Authorization": "Basic " + credentials
   },
    url: _url,
    success: function(data, text) {
     //console.log(data);
     $("#container").empty();
     $("#container").append(data);
  $("#nav > li > ul ").addClass("verberg");
  $("#nav > li > ul > li > ul").addClass("verberg");
    }
  });
}


function loadPage(documentId) {
 
  if (!documentId) {
   documentId = "document-id";
  }

  var _url = "http://api.writeplace.nl/=" +  documentId;

 var credentials = btoa("username:password!");
 
  
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
     "Authorization": "Basic " + credentials
   },
    url: _url,
    success: function(data, text) {
     $("#tekst").empty();
     $("#tekst").append(data);
    }
  });
}




 

function uitvouwen(){

function uitvouwen1(){
 $("#container").on("click", "#nav > li", function(){

  $(this).children().toggleClass("verberg");
  //console.log("khbvdkvbedkvbewdkvfjbwekbfwkdjbvkejdbv");
 });
}


function uitvouwen2(){
 $("#container").on("click", "#nav > li > ul > li", function(){
  $(this).children().toggleClass("verberg");
  //console.log("gffhgfhh");
  
 });
}


uitvouwen2();
uitvouwen1();



}
```

The navigation is loaded and the most upper `ul` has the id `nav`. On `document.ready` I add the class  `hide` to `#nav>li>ul` and `#nav>li>ul>li>ul`, so the `li` items are set to hide by default. The problem with this list however is that if you click a link or a deeper down `li` item in the tree, it registers this also as a click on the levels above.

Is there a way to fix this? Or a better (cleaner) way to make collapsible nested lists with dynamic content?

Comment: You need some kind of path control. So when somebody clicks a link, the function can actually determine which link was clicked. You can do this by using classes or the [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: To help you further, we need more code. The HTML for the list and the function `loadnavigation`. Could you update your snippet so it works with the basic version you have?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've updated the snippet with the rest of the j-query things. Is there any way I can add path control with my jquery file? (I do not have acces to the original server file, someone else is managing those)

Comment: Yes you can, when the elements are appended, you get control of it. Could you post the rendered output?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pr95mq6f/1/ uploaded everything to  jsfiddle something seems to be wrong, the link show s a not working jquery site, I'll try to fix it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pr95mq6f/1/ now it should work? It should show a decent kind of site, if it's text and links something is wrong. The navigation is under the button in the top-left corner.

Comment: The basic structure of my answer is kept intact. I've adapted it to be used in your application. http://jsfiddle.net/pr95mq6f/3/

Comment: thank you for your help! I have accepted your answer, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how I would do this. I used an `data-id`. attribute. This can come in handy when assigning functions to the menu. You can always travel down or up using the ids. It hides/shows the `UL` by finding an ancestor or itself containing a `data-attribute`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav").html(loadnavigation(menu, null)); //to load the li items//
  $("#container").click(function(e){
    //e refers to the click event. 
    //bind it
    var eventTarget = $(e.target);

    //we need to use closest here. If you append other HTML-elements to the li, eventTarget
    //will refer to these elements. This way, it always travels up to the 
    //closest ancestor with an data-id attribute.
    eventTarget.closest("li[data-id]").children("ul").toggleClass("hide"); //find the closest ancestor (or self) that has data-id and hide its ul.
    
  });
});

//below is my own code just to show an example of my comment:

//I'm using a array, combined with objects to build the basic structure of the menu.
var menu = [{
  name: "list 1",
  menu: [{
    name: "sublist 1"
  }, {
    name: "sublist 2"
  }]
}, {
  name: "list 2",
  menu: [{
    name: "sublist 1",
    menu: [{
      name: "sublist 1"
    }, {
      name: "sublist 2"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "sublist 2"
  }]
}, {
  name: "list 3"
}];

function loadnavigation(obj, dataID) {
  var html = ""; //using var here is important. We want this variable to be private and within the scope of only this function.
  //this will be a recursive function.
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var id = i;
    if (dataID != null || dataID != undefined) //we start the function at first with value null.
    {
      id = dataID + "-" + id; //separate id's from eachother with a dash   
    }
    var menuItem = '<li data-id="' + id + '">';
    menuItem += obj[i].name; //append the menu name with +=
    if (obj[i].menu) //obj has submenu
    {
      menuItem += "<ul class='hide'>" + loadnavigation(obj[i].menu, id) + "</ul>";
    }
    menuItem += "</li>"; //close
    html += menuItem;
  }
  return html;
}
```

```css
ul.hide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul id="nav">

  </ul>
</div>
```

The code should explain itself.

Why do I find the `data-attribute` convenient:

```
$("li[data-id^='1-']")
```

The selector above will select all children that are part of the tree branch starting with id 1.